# Factorization in a Group

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups, factoring

$5$ is a prime number, but it can be expressed as $2*3*3$ mod $13$.

So I am wondering if we are given a number $l$ and a prime $p$ that is smaller than $l$ but doesn't divide it, can we write write $p$ as a product of a small number of small factors (mod $l$)?

And here by small I mean some function of l like $\log(l)$ or $log(l)^2$ or even $l^\epsilon$ where $\epsilon < 1$.

Thanks.

Comment: When we are thinking (mod l), there is no such thing as prime numbers.

Comment: @IvanNeretin that's true but irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It is known that a group can be generated by its elements smaller than $O(\lg^2 n)$... so we just need a similar bound on the exponent of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best known bound for a quadratic the least quadratic non-residue modulo a prime $l$ is as far as I know (see [Burgess - The distribution of quadratic residues and non-residues](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/res/burgess.pdf))
$$ \ll l^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt{e}}} $$
thought it is conjectured to be much smaller.

Now the least quadratic non-residue is a prime, and given any factorization it will have necessarily at least a prime quadratic non-residue on it. This means that the least order of magnitude you may hope for with current knowledge is $l^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt{e}}} $.

On the positive side, according to [this paper](http://www.nieuwarchief.nl/serie5/pdf/naw5-2000-01-4-380.pdf) for any $p \pmod{l}$ you can find $a,b \ll l^{3/4}$ such that $ab \equiv p \pmod{l}$,
so this gives $\epsilon \le \frac{3}{4}$ in your factorization.

Note: the symbol $\ll A$ means a constant times $A$, it is similar to $O(A)$.

Comment: Many thanks. Can you please link me to the paper that proves that there always exist an $a$ such that $a,a^{-1} << l^{\frac{3}{4}}$.

Comment: @kyloc, I found the paper and it directly cover your case so I'm updating the answer.

Comment: many thanks ! this is great.

Comment: The paper handles the problem once $l$ is prime. What happens if $l$ is not prime?

Comment: I found this paper: http://www.integers-ejcnt.org/n12/n12.pdf that proves the same result for the case where $l$ is not prime but $gcd(l,p)=1$... and that is enough for what I am doing. Thanks.